# How can we remove all type of skype in a computer using powershell or any batch scripting

Tags: powershell

T tried to remove skype with this codes

1. `powershell -Command "Get-AppxPackage -allusers *Microsoft.SkypeApp* | Remove-AppxPackage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue"`
2. `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*skype*"} | ForEach-Object { $_.Uninstall() }`

but when I query with this

1. `Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.SkypeApp`

still outputs this

```
Name                   : Microsoft.SkypeApp
Publisher              : CN=Skype Software Sarl, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Luxembourg, S=Luxembourg, C=LU
Architecture           : X64
ResourceId             :
Version                : 15.113.3210.0
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.113.3210.0_x64__kzf8qxf38zg5c
InstallLocation        :
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c
PublisherId            : kzf8qxf38zg5c
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-3103298544-3233076758-2911027781-1002 [USER]: Staged}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
NonRemovable           : False
IsPartiallyStaged      : False
SignatureKind          : Store
Status                 : Ok
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Powershell; but isn't the obvious explanation that it still knows something about the package even if it is not installed?

Comment: I'd recommend running `powershell -Command "Get-AppxPackage -allusers *Microsoft.SkypeApp* | Remove-AppxPackage"` without the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` part so that you can see if it's failing. Skype is still staged on your system even though it's not installed, but according to https://superuser.com/questions/1727847/removing-a-staged-appxpackage what you already tried should have removed it (unless you weren't running that command as an Administrator, in which case do that).

Comment: If you have the required permissions to uninstall from that particular users account, then the first thing I'd suggest is this: ```%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *SkypeApp* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue"```. I'd also not be immediately checking again, and probably wait until after a log out/reboot.

Comment: thanks for these ideas. i will try those in later and have a feedback for you guys. thanks for your time. :D